# Where does the "hierarchal" view get put in the eclipse plugin?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

Since the 2.3 update finding the window that shows the parts in an xml sdk has been impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the Outline View? Its there for me.

1. Choose `Window` > `Show View ...` > `Other`. Then open the `General` folder at the top and select `Outline`. Click `OK`.
2. Or else try reseting your perspective.  Choose `Window` > `Reset Perspective...`

Comment: thanks, was looking in android and xml view, didn't think to look in general. :)